# Wie nennt man den abgebildeten Gegenstand (Button) auf deutsch?

Tags: single-word-request

Ich würde gern wissen wie man diesen Gegenstand nennt. In der Beschreibung zum Bild stand »Buttons«. Es ist aber ein englisches Wort. Es muss doch ein deutsches Wort dafür geben.

Das Wort *Knopf* scheint mir nicht besonders geeignet zu sein. Hat jemand eine Idee?

**EDIT:** Leider hat Wrzlprmft meine Frage so geändert dass es nun eine ganz andere Bedeutung hat. Das man die Dinge **Button** nennt war mir von Anfang an klar und steht überhaupt nicht zur Debatte. Ich wollte nur wissen ob es einen **rein deutschen Begriff** für diesen Gegenstand gibt oder früher mal gab. Nicht um es irgendwo zu verwenden, sondern rein aus Interesse. Leider kam es irgendwie nicht an...

[image: buttons]

Comment: Ich habe in der Edit-History nachgesehen. Wrzlprmft hat die Bedeutung der Frage überhaupt nicht verändert. Er hat im Text-Teil der Frage Korrekturen bei den Anführungszeichen gemacht, den passenden tag vergeben, und in der Überschrift das eingeklammerte Wort »(Button)« eingefügt. Der Grund dafür ist auch klar: Wenn man die Überschrift in der Liste der Fragen (also hier: http://german.stackexchange.com ) sieht, weiß man sonst nicht, welcher Gegenstand gemeint ist. Der Rest der Überschrift stammt 1:1 von dir selbst, und der Fließtext blieb, von den Anführungszeichen abgesehen, sowieso gleich.

Comment: Kommentare sind nicht für Antworten und Diskussionen darüber gedacht. [Die Diskussion wurde in den Chat verschoben.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43585/discussion-on-question-by-dit-wie-nennt-man-den-abgebildeten-gegenstand-button) Ich schlage vor, dass sie jemand ausschlachtet, um eine ausführliche Antwort über das Für und Wider der Option *Ansteckplakette* u. Ä. zu schreiben.

Comment: Als Ergänzung zu dem was @Hubert gesagt hat: Angenommen, jemand sucht wie Du ein deutsches Wort für *Button.* Dann wird er viel eher auf ein Suchergebnis klicken, dass dieses Wort explizit erwähnt statt nur »Wie nennt man den abgebildeten Gegenstand auf deutsch?«. Die Änderung des Titels hilft also so jemandem, fündig zu werden. Dass *Button* nicht das Wort ist, das Du suchst, ging vorher wie nachher klar aus der Frage hervor, **gerade weil** Du es explizit erwähnst.

Answer (score 10):

So ein Gegenstand heißt auf deutsch:

### Button

Laut Duden ist ein [Button](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Button) eine "runde Plakette zum Anstecken [mit einer Aufschrift], die die politische, religiöse o. ä. Einstellung des Trägers, der Trägerin zu erkennen gibt". Button gehört zur Klasse der dritthäufigsten Wörter, ist also ein allgemein geläufiges Wort und den meisten Sprechern bekannt. Einen Eintrag für "[Ansteckplakette](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Ansteckplakette)" gibt es im Duden nicht.

Das Wort ist männlich (»der Button«), die Aussprache richtete sich nach englischen Ausspracheregeln (also [ˈbatn̩]). Im Plural wird in allen vier Fällen ein s angefügt (»die Buttons«), ebenso im Genitiv Singular (»des Buttons«). Dativ und Akkusativ Singular bleiben unverändert (»den Button«).

Das englische Wort dafür ist nicht »button«, sondern »**badge**« oder »**pinback**«. Die Situation ist vergleichbar mit der deutschen Bezeichnung »Handy« für Mobiltelefone, die zwar ebenfalls ein englisches Wort ist, im englischen Sprachraum aber nicht auf diese Weise verwendet wird. (Im Englischen ist »button« ein Knopf, z.B: an einer Jacke, um sie zuknöpfen zu können, oder auch ein Schalter der gedrückt werden kann.)

Entstanden ist das Wort aus dem englischen »pinback button«, das bedeutet in etwa: »Knopf, der hinten eine Nadel hat«. Dieser Zweiwort-Begriff existiert als solcher zwar nach wie vor im Englischen, jedoch ist die Verkürzung »pinback« oder »pin-back« weitaus häufiger in Verwendung. In den deutschen Wortschatz hat es aber das andere Wort, eben der *Button*, geschafft. »Button« allein (ohne »pinback«) wird nur auf deutsch für die abgebildeten Gegenstände verwendet, nicht aber auf englisch.

Natürlich gibt es Synonyme, aber entweder sind das sperrige Worte wie »Ansteckplakette«, oder Begriffe, die eine etwas abweichende Bedeutung haben (Anstecknadel, Brosche, Orden). Daher ist der übliche und etablierte Begriff dafür eben *Button*.

Comment: wie gesagt an englischen Begriffen oder die, die aus dem englischen kommen war ich nicht interessiert. Wenn wir sperrige Wörter vermeiden wollen, dann können wir ja gleich zu englischen Sprache übergehen. Ich bin kein Muttersprachler, von daher bin ich an (alt)deutschen Begriffen interessiert. Sperrig oder nicht, einfach aus Interesse.

Comment: @dit Wie alle Sprachen übernimmt auch das Deutsche häufig Wörter aus anderen Sprachen. Diese Wörter sind für die Sprecher des Deutschen dann oft auch die gebräuchlichen und verständlichsten Begriffe. Alle Deutschen sagen z.B. "Telefon", und viele wissen nicht, was sie unter einem "Fernsprecher" verstehen sollen. Ob du nun an diesen Wörtern interessiert bist oder nicht, es sind nunmal einfach die korrekten Bezeichnungen. Wenn du nur "(alt)deutsche" Begriffe verwenden willst, dann wird es sehr schwer für dich, dich verständlich auf Deutsch auszudrücken.

Comment: Sehr schöne Erklärung, Hubert. Nicht alles, was Englisch klingt, ist auch Englisch :-)

Comment: @what das ist mir schon klar. Ich wollte nur wissen ob es früher mal anders hieß oder ob es einen rein deutschen Begriff gab. Button, Badge, Pinback. Ja super Sache. Aber nun mal zu Frage: wie ist der deutsche Begriff dazu. Die Antwort die ich wollte ist Ansteckplakette.

Comment: @dit Allerdings ist die Plakette (bzw. Plaquette) eigentlich französisch.

Comment: @dit Das Wort "Ansteckplakette" habe ich aber noch nie gehört. Wenn du es mir gegenüber verwenden würdest, würde ich nicht verstehen, was du meinst.

Comment: @what http://www.stylebutton.de/buttonlexikon/192-ansteckplaketten

Comment: @Uwe dann ist die Frage immer noch nicht gelöst :)

Comment: @dit Lach. Und das auf der Seite *style**button**.de*!

Comment: @dit: Du fragst »wie ist der deutsche Begriff dazu«. Diese Frage basiert auf der Prämisse, dass es zu jedem fremdsprachigen Begriff auch einen deutschen gibt. Diese Prämisse trifft aber nicht zu. Insbesondere gibt es für den Button kein rein deutsches Wort. »Button« kommt aus dem englischen, »Plakette« aus dem Französischen. Das einzige echte deutsche Wort, das annähernd diese Bedeutung hat, ist »Knopf«, aber dazu schreibst du selbst in deinem Frageposting: »Das Wort Knopf scheint mir nicht besonders geeignet zu sein«, und darin stimme ich dir voll zu.

Comment: Für mich ist die Diskussion zu Ende. Danke für eure Beiträge.

Comment: *Button* wird auch im Englischen verwendet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campaign_button https://shop.donaldjtrump.com/product-p/dtc-button-2016.htm

Answer (score 5):

Als Muttersprachler aus Südwestdeutschland kenne ich das Objekt vorrangig als

**Anstecker**

Wie in den Kommentaren zur Frage angemerkt wurde, ist *Anstecker* aber in der Tat etwas generischer als *Button*, da ein *Button* immer kreisförmig ist, während *Anstecker* beliebige Formen haben können. Somit scheint

**Button**

in der Tat des treffendste, kurze Wort zu sein.

---

Das in manchen Antworten vorgeschlagene *Ansteckplakette* würde ich mit Vorsicht genießen, da es zumindest meinem Eindruck nach nicht flächendeckend gebräuchlich ist (ich kannte es zumindest bis zu dieser Frage nicht). Intuitiv klingt es für mich zunächst auch eher nach "amtsdeutsch", auch wenn ich nicht ausschließen will, dass das Wort tatsächlich auch umgangssprachlich in Gebrauch ist/war. Was für mich aber ausschlaggebend bei der Entscheidung wäre, *Ansteckplakette* eher nicht zu verwenden, ist, dass ich selber nicht verstanden hätte, was es bedeuten soll, wäre mir hier die Bedeutung nicht durch den Kontext klargeworden.

Comment: Danke. Wenigstens einer. Auf die Form des Gegenstands habe ich nicht geachtet. Das erste Bild das ich fand habe ich auch hier gepostet.

Answer (score -1):

**Vorwort**

Das abgebildete Gegenstand wird aktuell meistens im Internet als **Button** bezeichnet. Das der Fakt und man sollte diesen Begriff auch verwenden.

Ich kann das nicht oft genug betonen: **dies war aber nicht gefragt**.

Um das Thema abzuschließen, möchte ich aber gern auf die ursprüngliche Frage zurückkommen. Meine Erwartung war - ein professionelle Meinung von jemanden der sich mit der Sprache und Altbegriffen auskennt und weniger "*das Wort habe ich noch nie gehört*".

Da ich mich sehr für solche alte Begriffe interessiere, wollte ich wissen, wie man so ein Gegenstand, also Button, **noch** bezeichnen kann bzw. **bezeichnet hat**.

Die Antwort, die ich wollte - **Ansteckplakette** bekam ich von [celtschk](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/1684/celtschk). Danke dafür.

Anscheinend wurde das Wort tatsächlich früher unter anderen in Norddeutschland verwendet.

---

**Verwendung von Ansteckplakette heute**

Das Wort Ansteckplakette wird heute noch verwendet. Es gibt also durchaus Menschen, die das Wort schon mal gehört haben. Vor allem für ältere Menschen ist die Bezeichnung Ansteckplakette geläufig. Hier sind nur einige Beipiele von vielen, die belegen, dass das Wort durchaus noch verwendet wird.

- [Schiffbautechnische Gesellschaft e.V. - Die Jahre 1901-1930](https://www.stg-online.org/stg/geschichte/1901-30.html)
- [Englisch-Deutsch-Wörterbuch: button](https://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/button.html) (Beachte Button hat hier technische Bedeutung)
- [Ansteckplakette für Behinderte](http://www.senioren-shop-munter.de/senioren-shop-sehen-hoeren/blinden-behindertenzeichen/ansteckplakette-fur-behinderte.html)
- [Google Suche - Bücher](https://www.google.de/search?tbm=bks&hl=de&q=Ansteckplakette%20)

---

**Suche über Google - Bilder**

Vergleichen wir nun die Suchergebnisse der Google Suche mit zwei Begriffen: Button vs Ansteckplakette:

- [Google Bilder: Ansteckplakette](https://www.google.de/search?safe=active&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=929&q=Ansteckplakette&oq=Ansteckplakette)
- [Google Bilder: Button](https://www.google.de/search?safe=active&biw=1920&bih=929&site=imghp&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=button&oq=button)

Vergleicht man die Ergebnisse mit einander, wird es einem klar wie vieldeutig das Wort Button doch ist.

---

**Schlußwort**

zum Schluß möchte ich wieder auf die [www.stylebutton.de](http://www.stylebutton.de/buttonlexikon/192-ansteckplaketten) Seite verweisen, was der Benutzer [what](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/4973/what) so lustig fand. Auch hier wurde ich leider mißverstanden. Man hat sich kurzsichtig auf das Wort **button** im Domainnamen konzentriert und weniger auf den Inhalt des Verweises.

Denn das wichtigste in dem von mir geteilten Link, war die Textbeschreibung (mit einer "versteckten" Botschaft):

> Der Begriff Ansteckplakette ist die deutsche sinngemäße Übersetzung von Buttons/Ansteckbuttons. Er wird eher selten verwendet, doch wenn Du ein Faible für den Erhalt der deutschen Sprache hast, verstehen wir Dich auch, wenn Du von Ansteckplaketten sprichst :-).

Ich bin kein Muttersprachler und wahrscheinlich deswegen habe ich diesen *Faible für den Erhalt der deutschen Sprache*. Das war auch der Grund für diese Frage.

Comment: Das aus dem englischen kommende Wort »Button« lehnst du an, aber das Wort »Plakette«, das einen französischen Ursprung hat, akzeptierst du als deutsch? Und wie ist dein Kommentar »*Für mich ist die Diskussion zu Ende.*« zu verstehen, den du ungefähr eine Stunde vor dieser Antwort gepostet hast?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast ja akzeptiere ich weitaus mehr als dein button. Ausserdem ist diese Anwort sollte als Diskussionsende aus meiner Sicht verstanden werden. Es dauert nun mal bis ich alles geschrieben habe.

Comment: Die vielen verschiedenen Bilder, die du bei der Suche nach »Button« bei Google findest, sind nur ein Beleg dafür, dass dieses Wort in einer anderen Sprache (nämlich Englisch) auch vorkommt, und dort eine andere Bedeutung als im Deutschen hat.

Comment: Die "Ansteckplakette" der Schiffsbaugesellschaft ist aber etwas völlig anderes, als der von dir abgebildete Button! Dort wird "Ansteckplakette" synonym für eine Anstecknadel gebraucht, also eine Auszeichnung oder Erinnerungsmedaille, die in der Regel eine dreidimensionale Form hat. Das ist etwas völlig anderes, als ein Blechbutton! Vielleicht solltest du den Muttersprachlern hier glauben ...

Comment: @what ok lassen wir das mit Schiffsbaugeschäft. Was ist mit anderen Beispielen vor allem in den Büchern. Hast du dazu auch irgendeine verzweifelte Ausrede?